# What's wrong with this (fake) proof that $ n=1\forall n\in \Bbb N$?

Tags: induction, fake-proofs

What's wrong with this (fake) proof that $ n=1\forall n\in \Bbb N$?

Base case: $n=1$ true.

$n-2,n-1<n+1\implies n-1=n-2\implies n+1=n=1$.

From the principle of induction it follows that $n=1 \forall n\in \Bbb N._\square$

This "proof" comes from a book of Enzo Gentile.

Comment: It seems to use $a,b<c\Rightarrow a=b$...

Comment: No, $n-2,n-1<n+1 \implies n-2=1, n-1=1$ by the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Right at the beginning something is stated very sloppily.

Comment: I know that case is false, but why doesn't this fail at the inductive step?

Comment: Induction step itself is true. The problem is that the induction is failed to be initiated.

Answer (score 3):

So, the base case $n=1$ is true. Then, to show it for $2$, we start out with the statement
$$-1,0<2$$
and then concludes that $-1=0$, despite that neither $-1$ nor $0$ are covered in this induction. That is, it reaches "before" the base cases. If we had $-1=1$ and $0=1$, this would be valid. But those are, of course, false.

Comment: So the problem is that $\mathbb{N}$ isn't closed under subtraction, right?

Comment: @Sambo Basically. The proof assumes that $n-2\in\mathbb N$ whenever $n\in \mathbb N$.